# Typescript - NodeJS - Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, typescript

I've just started using typescript for NodeJS Server development and I've run into the following errors:

```
./app/api/shoutbox/shoutbox.dao.ts
error TS2339: Property 'statics' does not exist on type 'Schema'

./app/api/shoutbox/shoutbox.controller.ts
error TS2339: Property 'getAll' does not exist on type 'Model<Document>'.

./app/api/shoutbox/shoutbox.controller.ts
error TS2339: Property 'catch' does not exist on type 'Promise<{}>'.
```

I am using Webpack and TS-Loader. And I've referenced

```
/// <reference path="mongoose/mongoose.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="node/node.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="express/express.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="mime/mime.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="serve-static/serve-static.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="lodash/lodash.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="bluebird/bluebird.d.ts" />



// shoutbox.model.ts
import mongoose = require('mongoose'); 
var _shoutboxSchema = {
    author: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
     },
     msg: String
};
export default new mongoose.Schema(_shoutboxSchema);


// shoutbox.dao.ts
import mongoose = require('mongoose');
import Promise = require('bluebird');
import _ = require('lodash');
import shoutboxSchema from './shoutbox.model';

shoutboxSchema.statics.getAll = ():Promise<any> => {
    var _promise = (resolve:Function, reject:Function):void => {
        var _query = {};
        Shoutbox
             .find(_query)
             .exec((err, shoutbox) => {
                err ? reject(err)
                    : resolve(shoutbox);
             });
    };
    return new Promise (_promise);
};
var Shoutbox = mongoose.model('Shoutbox', shoutboxSchema);
export default Shoutbox;

// shoutbox.controller.ts
import ShoutboxDAO from './shoutbox.dao';
import express = require("express");

export class ShoutboxController {
    static  getAll(req:express.Request, res:express.Response):void {
         ShoutboxDAO
            .getAll()
            .then(shoutbox => res.status(200).json(shoutbox))
            .catch(error => res.status(400).json(error));
    }
}
```

I've tried around for quite some time now but i cant get rid of the errors.

The code itself runs as intended but i keep getting these errors.

Im thankful for any sort of help.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered similar problems with using the mongoose.d.ts from DefinitelyTyped github repo. It seems it isn't correctly matching the mongoose javascript. I instead use the one from here https://github.com/vagarenko/mongoose-typescript-definitions.